# How do I make a xamarin forms app with two different front ends?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an app written xamarin forms 5.  I have the iOS and Androiud version in their respective stores.  Now I want to create another app (iOS and droid) which is essentially the same app with a differet looking UI.  Let's say it is purely UI/XAML changes.

I can't just copy the project with the AppShell in it as the iOS and droid projects reference the original and not the copy
.
I don't want to have to unload projects as it like to upload it and use it in App Centre.

I'm guessing I could move the .xaml files into another project (leaving all the viewmodels, etc) and then just have a copy of this for each app.  It would mean two solutions each with the different xaml project but everything else the same.

Are there any better suggestions?

Comment: Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/

Comment: My bad.  That gives you an app with the same UI in different colours.  I am thinking different flyout menu, menu items, colours, images, etc.  Essentially two different AppShell .xaml files.

Comment: There is not a better way , we have to  copy the project and change the `.xaml` files manually ..

Comment: @ThirdPrize It's not just colours that you can change

Comment: @Andrei I suppose I could template it all.  But I would still need two "App" projects referencing the same ios/droid projects as I need to build two apps.  In which case I might as well just do the UI straight in XAML and not template it.     I have a library with the domain spoecific code in it.  I tried copying my view models into a separate project but they all reference the App object. so i would have to duplicate the whole "App" project, which i don't want to do.

Comment: I've read the question again. You're having issues changing the package name and app name from their respective projects in order to publish them? I never tried to publish the same app... but don't know if there's an issue if you change their details in the Manifest/AssemblyInfo

Comment: I don't think I can do what I want.  In xcode, i seem to remember you could have two targets (different version of the app) and then you could add the same file twice (?).  You would assign one file to each target, then when you built that target it only found and used that version of the file.  VS doesn't do that.

Comment: Yes, We can easily create two targets for the same project and manage them , but vs does not provide such function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created a branch in GIT for the new app.  I then changed the app UI in the branch to the new apps UI.  I can still send changes back and forth between the branch and main.  I guess that will probably do for now.